# Angular radio buttons - how to work around same name and form Controle Name case?

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to make simple form to choose car for every employee from list of cars avaliable for particular employee : 
Employee1 : car1, car2, car3 
Employee2 : car4, car5, car6 
Employee3 : car6, car8, car9

problem is in fact, that I can't have different formControleName and name of radioButton,

every employee field has 3 radio buttons which will assign values to ChosenCar for every employee, but this approach does not work. **Here is simple example code :** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-12-hthhkf?file=src/app/app.component.html

**FormGroup** 
companyName 
city 
employees

> employee1

Name, 
Age, 
ChosenCar

> employee2

Name, 
Age, 
ChosenCar

> employee3

Name, 
Age, 
ChosenCar

Comment: Read your question a few times, but did not understand your requirement. Each employee should be allowed to select one/multiple radio buttons for `chosenCar`? And what will be the value for `chosenCar` if the radio button is selected? `marka`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question right, but how does your data model look like?
That's how I usually start, from what I want to have in the end.
Here, I would create a formArray for the employees, in each of them exists a formArray for the cars which might consist of key-value pairs for the radio buttons' display names and values behind. The ControlValueAccessor interface comes in handy for such cases.